# How to keep the same scale/levels across different kdeplot (seaborn 2D plot)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I plot seaborn's `kdeplot` using subsets of a dataset. the main dataset contains people detections and are the coordinates on a map.There can be many detections in a single frame. the data contains detections of 24 hours

> Data format : `[time/frame_number, x_cordinate, y_cordinate]`

**Problem** 
When i draw two different `kdeplot` using two subsets data (say **1-2pm and 10-11pm**), Both plots are drawn fine.

By exploring the the data i found out that **1-2pm** is rush hour, where there are many detections and **10-11pm** is closing time where detections are way less. but `kdeplot` represents the data in same scale (red density areas). This behavior is understandable, Since kde defines the scale based on local max and min values.

**Requirement**
I want to plot hour-wise kde plots, but i want the scale to be constant over the whole day. Meaning, if **1-2pm** is rush-hour, the red density areas are shown there. but at **10-11pm** when there mild traffic, the color should not be red, rather lower density colors (green, blue), Since as compared to rush-hour the detections would be very less.

Inshort making scale/levels based on 24 hour min, max values and using consistently in hour-wise plots

Comment: A kernel density estimate is always normalized, such that the integral is 1. A different scaling is hence rather related to a different *spread* of the data, not the number of occurences. Therefore I'm not sure what you really want to show? Maybe a KDE is not at all suited to what you're after?

Comment: Hmm. the idea is to show a heatmap on the floor map (image) rather than simple dots (detection points), where heatmap gradient (red-to-blue shade) represents density of detections. Now lets say at 1-2pm, there were 200 people in a certain location, and from 10-11pm there were 40 people in that same location. When i plot two kdeplots on hour-wise data, 40 in 10-11pm is given the same gradient (red) as the 200 in 1-2pm. I may be using kde where i am not supposed to. can you suggest some other plot?. Thanks

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think what you want is to plot the kde times the total number of occurences. Or maybe just the 2d histogram?